# CMake custom command that depends on message generation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a catkin package that contains a bunch of custom messages.
In that same package I have a python script that generates a file based on the custom message definitions.
The python script `import`s the messages in question to generate its output file.

I am having trouble getting this to work from a clean workspace.

Here is how I have added my custom command:

```
set(COMPARATOR_MESSAGES
  msg/Foo.msg
  msg/Bar.msg
  msg/Baz.msg)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT include/message_comparators.hpp
  COMMAND scripts/generate_message_comparators.py
      --msg ${COMPARATOR_MESSAGES}
      --out include/message_comparators.hpp
  DEPENDS ${COMPARATOR_MESSAGES} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_genpy
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
  COMMENT "Generating message comparators"
  )

add_custom_target(part_out ALL DEPENDS include/message_comparators.hpp)
```

This works fine if this catkin package has already been build once.
The problem I have is that when I run `catkin clean --yes; catkin build my_msgs`, it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/generate_message_comparators.py", line 65, in <module>
    generate_comparator(message)
  File "scripts/generate_message_comparators.py", line 22, in generate_comparator
    i = importlib.import_module(message_namespace + ".msg")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named my_msgs.msg
make[2]: *** [include/message_comparators.hpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/part_out.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I thought I fixed the dependency problems with all the `DEPENDS` I added. I used to have the problem that, when I e.g. added a field to Foo.msg, the output of my custom command would not reflect that the first time I ran `catkin build my_package` because my command apparently ran before the messages were generated. `catkin build`-ing a second time would generate the correct result. Since adding `${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}`  (I think that's the only important one), this problem has been solved.

However, for some reason I still can't import the messages during the initial build.

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349996/cmake-custom-command-that-depends-on-message-generation/) by [NickDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/20638/nickdp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2020-04-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> In that same package I have a python script that generates a file based on the custom message definitions.

Although I don't know whether you meant "custom message" is ROS-based or not,

if ROS-based, you wouldn't need your own custom setup to build? ROS defines a standard way to build the message definition you define. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_msg

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2022-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0